# When is the coarse moduli space of genus $g$ stable curves smooth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, coarse-moduli-spaces

Let $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ be the moduli stack of genus $g$ stable (nodal) curves and let $\overline{M}_g$ denote its coarse moduli space. In 1969, in the paper "The irreducibility of the space of curves of given genus", Deligne and Mumford constructed and showed that $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ is a smooth Deligne-Mumford stack, and proved that $\overline{M}_g$ is an irreducible projective variety. Although $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ is smooth, $\overline{M}_g$ may have finite quotient singularity.

**When is $\overline{M}_g$ smooth?**

The simplest case is $\overline{M}_0$, which is a point and hence smooth by definition. My question is then equivalent to the following: for which $g>0$ is $\overline{M}_g$ smooth? Is it never smooth?

**Edit 1:**
I forgot to mention the base scheme is $\text{Spec }\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $M_g$ is not smooth for $g>1$, because of the presence of curves with extra automorphisms.

Comment: @abx Are you saying $M_1$ is smooth but $M_g$ is not smooth for every $g>1$?

Comment: Yes. This goes back to H. Rauch, *The singularities of the modulus space*, 
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 68 (1962), 390–394.

Comment: @abx Did the paper prove that for every $g>1$, there exists a stable nodal curve of genus $g$ with nontrivial automorphism?

Comment: No, I am talking here about $M_g$, not $\overline{M}_g$. But that's fairly trivial: take a smooth curve with an automorphism fixing a point, and add an elliptic tail.

Comment: @abx I meant to ask: Did the paper prove that for every $g>1$, there exists a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$ which has a nontrivial automorphism?

Comment: This is obvious, just take hyperelliptic curves.

Comment: @abx I don't know much about hyperelliptic curves, so it's not obvious to me. But I have one more doubt: the existence of nontrivial automorphism of a curve doesn't imply the corresponding isomorphism class is a singular point in the coarse moduli. For example, think about $M_{1,1}$, if we allow marked point into discussion. Every marked elliptic curve has a nontrivial automorphism but the coarse moduli is smooth.

Comment: Sorry, this is enough for me. Look at the reference I gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more detailed description of the singular locus of $\mathrm{M}_g$ is as follows.

**Theorem.** Let $\mathrm{C}$ be a smooth curve of genus $g$.

If $g=2$, then $[\mathrm{C}]$ is a singular point of $\mathrm{M}_2$ if and only if $\mathrm{C}$ is given by $y^2=x^6-x$.

If $g=3$ and $\mathrm{C}$ is not hyperelliptic (resp. hyperelliptic), then $[\mathrm{C}]$ is a singular point of $\mathrm{M}_3$ if and only if $\mathrm{Aut(C)}$ is nontrivial (resp. $\mathrm{Aut(C)}$ is not $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$).

If $g\geqslant 4$, then $[\mathrm{C}]$ is a singular point of $\mathrm{M}_g$ if and only if $\mathrm{Aut(C)}$ is nontrivial.

An algebro-geometric reference for this result is [this paper by H. Popp](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82439366.pdf).

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. Can you add the case $g=1$ to make it a complete answer?

Comment: @YuhangChen: we have $\mathrm{M}_1\simeq\mathbf{A}^1$ (in particular there are no singularities), but I think it is most natural to restrict the discussion to $g\geqslant 2$.

Comment: Yes, and $\overline{M}_1 \cong \mathbb{P}^1$, right?

Comment: @YuhangChen: Sure

Answer (score 0):

The question is mostly answered by abx's comments. Here I'm posting a self-contained answer so that it will be helpful for the others.

**Case 1: $g=0$**

$M_0 = \overline{M}_0$ is just a point and is smooth, as already mentioned in the question.

**Case 2: $g=1$**
Now there is a subtlety. Actually $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_1$ is not a Deligne-Mumford stack because every elliptic curve has an infinite group of automorphisms, i.e., translations. It's more meaningful to talk about $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$, the moduli stack of curves with genus $g=1$ and one marked point (we don't want to forget the group structure of elliptic curves, which has the marked point as the identity) and its compactification $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{1,1}$. We know the coarse moduli space $\overline{M}_{1,1}$ is isomorphic to the weighted projective line $\mathbb{P}(4,6)$ and hence is smooth.

**Case 3: $g\geq2$**

By Theorem 1 in the paper "The singularities of the modulus space" by Rauch in 1962, we know $M_g$ must have some point of singularity and hence its compactification $\overline{M}_g$ is singular.